# CSS Masonry UI not working properly using `column-count` and `box-shadow`

Tags: html, css

The Below is my code of a ***Masonry UI***, I am using with pure **CSS**

This works well if there are more than *4 cards* but if I use it with below *4 cards* the `column-count: 3;` does not work well.

```css
body{
  height:1000px;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-gap: 1em;
    -webkit-column-gap: 1em;
    column-gap: 1em;
    padding: 0px 4px 4px 4px;
    margin-top: -10px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    
}

li {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    box-shadow: none;
    background: transparent;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 2%;
}

li div {
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: #f4faff;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.84);
    margin-top: 1em;
    cursor: pointer;
}

li div img{
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><div><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQs7OT7p9xBXn090AjKYgX4eV6vr-kHsmbIfcSFh__PoXgdNtb5gg" alt=""></div></li>
    <li><div><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQs7OT7p9xBXn090AjKYgX4eV6vr-kHsmbIfcSFh__PoXgdNtb5gg" alt=""></div></li>
    <li><div><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQs7OT7p9xBXn090AjKYgX4eV6vr-kHsmbIfcSFh__PoXgdNtb5gg" alt=""></div></li>
    <li><div><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQs7OT7p9xBXn090AjKYgX4eV6vr-kHsmbIfcSFh__PoXgdNtb5gg" alt=""></div></li>
</ul>
<br><br><br>
BUT THIS WORKS IF THERE IS MORE THAN 4 IMAGES

<ul>
    <li><div><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQs7OT7p9xBXn090AjKYgX4eV6vr-kHsmbIfcSFh__PoXgdNtb5gg" alt=""></div></li>
    <li><div><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQs7OT7p9xBXn090AjKYgX4eV6vr-kHsmbIfcSFh__PoXgdNtb5gg" alt=""></div></li>
    <li><div><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQs7OT7p9xBXn090AjKYgX4eV6vr-kHsmbIfcSFh__PoXgdNtb5gg" alt=""></div></li>
    <li><div><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQs7OT7p9xBXn090AjKYgX4eV6vr-kHsmbIfcSFh__PoXgdNtb5gg" alt=""></div></li>
    <li><div><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQs7OT7p9xBXn090AjKYgX4eV6vr-kHsmbIfcSFh__PoXgdNtb5gg" alt=""></div></li>
    <li><div><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQs7OT7p9xBXn090AjKYgX4eV6vr-kHsmbIfcSFh__PoXgdNtb5gg" alt=""></div></li>
</ul>
```

> Tried Soluition:

```css
body{
  height:500px;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-gap: 1em;
    -webkit-column-gap: 1em;
    column-gap: 1em;
    padding: 0px 4px 4px 4px;
    margin-top: -10px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    overflow:visible;
    
}

li {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    float:left;
    background: transparent;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 2%;
}

li div {
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: #f4faff;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.84);
    margin-top: 1em;
    cursor: pointer;
}

li div img{
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><div><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQs7OT7p9xBXn090AjKYgX4eV6vr-kHsmbIfcSFh__PoXgdNtb5gg" alt=""></div></li>
    <li><div><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQs7OT7p9xBXn090AjKYgX4eV6vr-kHsmbIfcSFh__PoXgdNtb5gg" alt=""></div></li>
    <li><div><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQs7OT7p9xBXn090AjKYgX4eV6vr-kHsmbIfcSFh__PoXgdNtb5gg" alt=""></div></li>
    <li><div><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQs7OT7p9xBXn090AjKYgX4eV6vr-kHsmbIfcSFh__PoXgdNtb5gg" alt=""></div></li>
</ul>
```

I have used  `float: left;` to the above solutions `<li>` and it works in this case but in my real view it crops down the last `img's` **`box-shadow`** check the below screenshot.
[image]

Any solutions will be highly helpfull.

Comment: If it works in isolation away from your 'real view' you need to tell us what you're using/doing elsewhere. As a guess though, have you made sure `overflow:visible` has been applied to the containing element?

Comment: @dom_ahdigital I have re-created the bug please do have a look.

Comment: @weBBer this might be helpful [Pure css example](https://codepen.io/jh3y/pen/mPgyqw)

Comment: @Matt can you post that sample code as an answer with my UI, if it works I will be happy to mark as answer and give you the bounty.

Comment: @weBBer I have tried to modify the example code, using your images and applying the box shadow. I hope it could be helpful

Answer (score 1):

I hope something like this could be helpful.

```css
.dw {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 -webkit-column-gap: 0;
 column-gap: 0;
 position: relative;
}
.dw * {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}


@media (min-width: 768px) {
.dw {
 -webkit-column-count: 2;
 column-count: 2;
}
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
.dw {
 -webkit-column-count: 3;
 column-count: 3;
}
}

@media (min-width: 1500px) {
.dw {
 -webkit-column-count: 4;
 column-count: 3;
}
}
.dw-pnl {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 5px;
}
.dw-pnl__cntnt {
 border-radius: 3px;
 overflow: hidden;
 padding: 20px;
 width: 100%;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
.dw-pnl {
 -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
 break-inside: avoid;
}
}
img {
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.84);
}
img.dw-pnl__cntnt {
 padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="dw">
  <div class="dw-pnl "> <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQs7OT7p9xBXn090AjKYgX4eV6vr-kHsmbIfcSFh__PoXgdNtb5gg" alt="img1" class="dw-pnl__cntnt"/> </div>
  <div class="dw-pnl "> <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQs7OT7p9xBXn090AjKYgX4eV6vr-kHsmbIfcSFh__PoXgdNtb5gg" alt="img2" class="dw-pnl__cntnt"/> </div>
  <div class="dw-pnl "> <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQs7OT7p9xBXn090AjKYgX4eV6vr-kHsmbIfcSFh__PoXgdNtb5gg" alt="img3" class="dw-pnl__cntnt"/> </div>
  <div class="dw-pnl "> <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQs7OT7p9xBXn090AjKYgX4eV6vr-kHsmbIfcSFh__PoXgdNtb5gg" alt="img3" class="dw-pnl__cntnt"/> </div>
  <div class="dw-pnl "> <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQs7OT7p9xBXn090AjKYgX4eV6vr-kHsmbIfcSFh__PoXgdNtb5gg" alt="img3" class="dw-pnl__cntnt"/> </div>
  <div class="dw-pnl "> <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQs7OT7p9xBXn090AjKYgX4eV6vr-kHsmbIfcSFh__PoXgdNtb5gg" alt="img3" class="dw-pnl__cntnt"/> </div>
 
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Ty for your answer but it's `box-shadow` crops if you use bug images.

Comment: Sorry @weBBer, what do you mean? I will try to fix that :) p.s. I have tried to add more images and it still looks good.

Comment: Please check this link - https://jsfiddle.net/phrj3evk/2/, I hope you saw the issue of misalignment between the Images.

Answer (score 1):

The root cause here seems to be the `display: inline-block` on the `li` elements. Changing this to `block` should wrap them into columns.

```
li {
    width: 25%;
    display: block;
    box-shadow: none;
    background: transparent;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 2%;
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Your answer was the closest I think what I want, But there are still issues but it can be solved, so if you paste my sample code and prove your answer then I will be happy to mark it the one and grand you the bounty.

Comment: Be aware than removing *inline-block* could cause elements to be split between 2 columns (part of the element in one column and the rest of the element on the other

Comment: @vals can you suggest any solution.?

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is not kind of proper solution but it worked well for me when I was using masonry 
The thing is remove `column-count` property and just give width to `li` such as `width:25%;` or `width:300px;`
and use `flex-box` to maintain it for responsiveness. (it's up to you to use flex-box)

```css
body{
  height:1000px;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
   
 
    padding: 0px 4px 4px 4px;
    margin-top: -10px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content:center;
    flex-wrap:wrap;/*suggested to use if you set width in px*/

    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    
}

li {
    width: 25%;
    display: inline-block;
    box-shadow: none;
    background: transparent;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 2%;
}

li div {
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: #f4faff;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.84);
    margin-top: 1em;
    cursor: pointer;
}

li div img{
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><div><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQs7OT7p9xBXn090AjKYgX4eV6vr-kHsmbIfcSFh__PoXgdNtb5gg" alt=""></div></li>
    <li><div><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQs7OT7p9xBXn090AjKYgX4eV6vr-kHsmbIfcSFh__PoXgdNtb5gg" alt=""></div></li>
    <li><div><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQs7OT7p9xBXn090AjKYgX4eV6vr-kHsmbIfcSFh__PoXgdNtb5gg" alt=""></div></li>
    <li><div><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQs7OT7p9xBXn090AjKYgX4eV6vr-kHsmbIfcSFh__PoXgdNtb5gg" alt=""></div></li>
</ul>
<br><br><br>
BUT THIS WORKS IF THERE IS MORE THAN 4 IMAGES

<ul>
    <li><div><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQs7OT7p9xBXn090AjKYgX4eV6vr-kHsmbIfcSFh__PoXgdNtb5gg" alt=""></div></li>
    <li><div><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQs7OT7p9xBXn090AjKYgX4eV6vr-kHsmbIfcSFh__PoXgdNtb5gg" alt=""></div></li>
    <li><div><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQs7OT7p9xBXn090AjKYgX4eV6vr-kHsmbIfcSFh__PoXgdNtb5gg" alt=""></div></li>
    <li><div><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQs7OT7p9xBXn090AjKYgX4eV6vr-kHsmbIfcSFh__PoXgdNtb5gg" alt=""></div></li>
    <li><div><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQs7OT7p9xBXn090AjKYgX4eV6vr-kHsmbIfcSFh__PoXgdNtb5gg" alt=""></div></li>
    <li><div><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQs7OT7p9xBXn090AjKYgX4eV6vr-kHsmbIfcSFh__PoXgdNtb5gg" alt=""></div></li>
</ul>
```

Without `flex-box`

```css
body{
  height:1000px;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
   
 
    padding: 0px 4px 4px 4px;
    margin-top: -10px;
 

    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    
}

li {
    width: 25%;
    display: inline-block;
    box-shadow: none;
    background: transparent;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 2%;
}

li div {
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: #f4faff;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.84);
    margin-top: 1em;
    cursor: pointer;
}

li div img{
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><div><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQs7OT7p9xBXn090AjKYgX4eV6vr-kHsmbIfcSFh__PoXgdNtb5gg" alt=""></div></li>
    <li><div><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQs7OT7p9xBXn090AjKYgX4eV6vr-kHsmbIfcSFh__PoXgdNtb5gg" alt=""></div></li>
    <li><div><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQs7OT7p9xBXn090AjKYgX4eV6vr-kHsmbIfcSFh__PoXgdNtb5gg" alt=""></div></li>
    <li><div><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQs7OT7p9xBXn090AjKYgX4eV6vr-kHsmbIfcSFh__PoXgdNtb5gg" alt=""></div></li>
</ul>
<br><br><br>
BUT THIS WORKS IF THERE IS MORE THAN 4 IMAGES

<ul>
    <li><div><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQs7OT7p9xBXn090AjKYgX4eV6vr-kHsmbIfcSFh__PoXgdNtb5gg" alt=""></div></li>
    <li><div><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQs7OT7p9xBXn090AjKYgX4eV6vr-kHsmbIfcSFh__PoXgdNtb5gg" alt=""></div></li>
    <li><div><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQs7OT7p9xBXn090AjKYgX4eV6vr-kHsmbIfcSFh__PoXgdNtb5gg" alt=""></div></li>
    <li><div><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQs7OT7p9xBXn090AjKYgX4eV6vr-kHsmbIfcSFh__PoXgdNtb5gg" alt=""></div></li>
    <li><div><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQs7OT7p9xBXn090AjKYgX4eV6vr-kHsmbIfcSFh__PoXgdNtb5gg" alt=""></div></li>
    <li><div><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQs7OT7p9xBXn090AjKYgX4eV6vr-kHsmbIfcSFh__PoXgdNtb5gg" alt=""></div></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The thing is bro I have different size of images and *Masonry UI* is the best option in that scenario to stack them up nice..

Comment: Hmm you are right then this solution might not work when i used it i was having fixed width images

Comment: The height of the `img` will change quite big too. so *Masonry UI* will be the best.